# Python Traceback: Key Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, slack, slack-api

I've been learning how to use Python and Slack for my class project. I'm particularly working on slack threads so I can direct message my entire class.

```
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient

slack_token = os.environ["xoxb-restofapitoken"]
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

sc.api_call(
"chat.postMessage",
channel="#general",
text="Hello from Python! :tada:",
thread_ts="1476746830.000003",
reply_broadcast=True

)
```

When I run the code, the error below shows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "chat1.py", line 4, in <module>
slack_token = os.environ["xoxb-restofapitoken"]
File "/home/ubuntu/starterbot/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'xoxb-restofapitoken'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I made the question clearer.

Comment: It looks like the environment variable doesn't exist. Are you sure it does? What's the result of `echo $xoxb-restofapitoken` ?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla, now it's showing `AttributeError: _Environ instance has no __call__ method`

Comment: For starters, you could print all the keys in `os.environ` and check if the required key exists. For example, if you put your slack token in a variable by doing `export SLACK_TOKEN='xoxb-restofapitoken'` you should access it by doing `os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']`. Currently the key error says that the slack token isn't available on your OS Environment variables.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla I've exported the token already. Is naming a possible error?

Comment: Can you share the command with which you exported the token?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla, Sure. I used `export SLACK_BOT_TOKEN='xoxb-restofapitoken'`

Comment: Then `slack_token = os.environ["xoxb-restofapitoken"]` should be `slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]` This is exactly what I explained in the previous comment.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla Maybe I'm just confused, but that's what I have but I replaced it with my token. What am I missing?

Comment: You shouldn't replace it with your token, as it's just the name of the variable which holds the token, not its value.
So do `export SLACK_BOT_TOKEN="your-api-token"` before you run your script and in your script replace the line with `slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]`.

Comment: That actually worked, thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

I've met similar error before.
There is nothing wrong with your code.
However, kindly follow Slack's [guideline](https://slackapi.github.io/python-slackclient/auth.html#test-tokens) when you are using test tokens , "pass tokens in as environment variables".

Change the code to:

```
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient

slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

sc.api_call(
"chat.postMessage",
channel="#general",
text="Hello from Python! :tada:",
thread_ts="1476746830.000003",
reply_broadcast=True

)
```

Run it with:

```
SLACK_BOT_TOKEN="xoxb-restofapitoken" python myapp.py
```

and you should be good to go.